# Probability stochastic process for all points of time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\{X(t):t\in[0,\infty)\}$ be a stochastic process and $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function.
If the probability
$$ \mathbb{P}(X(t)\leq f(t))$$
is known for all (fixed) $t\in[0,\infty)$, then, what can be said about the probability 
$$ \mathbb{P}(X(t)\leq f(t)~~\forall t\geq0)?$$

Comment: You can of course bound the latter probability in terms of the other ones.  But nothing more than that can be said.  For example, suppose we simplify to a (discrete time) sequence of random variables $\{X_t\}_{t=0}^{\infty}$ and we know $P[X_t \leq 1/2] = 1/2$ for all $t \in \{0,1,2,...\}$.  Then in simple cases when $X_t$ are i.i.d., or when $X_t=X_0$ for all $t$, or mixtures of these, you can make $P[X_t \leq 1/2,  \forall t \in \{0,1,2,...\}]$ any desired value in $[0,1/2]$.

Comment: On the other hand, in the special case when you know $P[X(t) \leq f(t)]=1$ for all $t \in \{0, 1, 2,…\}$ then you can conclude $P[X(t) \leq f(t) ,  \forall t \in \{0, 1, 2,…\}]=1$.  But for continuous time $t \in [0, \infty)$, if you know $P[X(t)\leq f(t)]=1$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$, you _cannot_ conclude $P[X(t)\leq f(t), \forall t \in [0,\infty]]=1$ (examples can be designed to make this probability any desired value in the interval $[0,1]$).

Comment: @Michael If I wanted to bound the latter probability, how am I supposed to do that? Is it $\mathbb{P}(X(t)\leq f(t)~\forall t\geq0)\leq\min_t \mathbb{P}(X(t)\leq f(t)$?

Comment: Yes, because for all $u \geq 0$ we have  $\{X(t) \leq f(t), \forall t \geq 0\} \subseteq \{X(u) \leq f(u)\}$. So for all $u \geq 0$ we have $$P[X(t) \leq f(t), \forall t \geq 0] \leq P[X(u) \leq f(u)]  $$ and you can take $\inf_{u \geq 0}$ of both sides (where only the right-hand-side depends on $u$).

Comment: @Michael Thank you. I wondered if there is also an upper boundary for $\mathbb{P}(X(t)>f(t)~~\text{for one}~t\geq0)$?

Comment: As I mentioned in my first comments, the best lower bound for $P[X(t) \leq f(t) , \forall t \geq 0]$ is 0.